# Why is TNSLSNR loading wrong listener?

Tags: oracle, listener

I'm using ORACLE 12c. I have 1 CDB and 1 PDB (for what I know).
To practice, I have created 2 listeners. I have made the appropriate settings in my tnsnames.ora file.

Observations:

- when I just run `lsnrctl start` i.e. without specifying one on my listeners name, **TNSLSNR actually loads a listener located in `/ora01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/db_1/bin/tnslsnr` (this is the path indicated by ps)
  Before running `lsnrctl start`, there is no listener.ora in `$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin`. I have renamed it to `xxxxxlistener.ora` for testing what "zombie" listener was loaded by simple `lsnrctl start`. The worst part is that the response message says it loaded a listener from `$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/listener.ora`. This is AWFUL since I renamed that file to `xxxxxlistener.ora`

There is a ghost file on my computer. Please help me as I can't even practice my custom listeners.

I can't practice my custom listener as if I don't put them on port 1521, I can NEVER user them to connect on the DB. That "ghost" listener seems to be messing things up

Answer (score 2):

> `lsnrctl START [listener_name]`
>
> In the preceding command, listener_name is the name of the listener defined in the `listener.ora` file. It is not necessary to identify the listener if you are using the default listener name LISTENER.

If you just hit `lsnrctl start` without the listener name then Oracle tries to start default listener which listens on two address:

```
(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=PNPKEY))
(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(PORT=1521))
```

If you wish to start a specific listener then, first of all define the listener in `listener.ora` file and specify listener name to start it as `lsnrctl start listener_name` as shown below:

```
[oracle@ora12c admin]$ lsnrctl start listener3

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production on 07-JAN-2017 19:53:16

Copyright (c) 1991, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Starting /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/db_1/bin/tnslsnr: please wait...

TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
System parameter file is /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/db_1/network/admin/listener.ora
Log messages written to /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/ora12c/listener3/alert/log.xml
Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.30.133)(PORT=1523)))

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.30.133)(PORT=1523)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     listener3
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
Start Date                07-JAN-2017 19:53:17
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 0 min. 0 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/db_1/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/ora12c/listener3/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.30.133)(PORT=1523)))
The listener supports no services
The command completed successfully
[oracle@ora12c admin]$ cat listener.ora 
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: /u01/app/grid/product/12.1.0/db_1/network/admin/listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

ENABLE_GLOBAL_DYNAMIC_ENDPOINT_LISTENER2 = ON

VALID_NODE_CHECKING_REGISTRATION_LISTENER = SUBNET

VALID_NODE_CHECKING_REGISTRATION_LISTENER2 = SUBNET

LISTENER1 =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.30.133)(PORT = 1522))
    )
  )

LISTENER3 =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.30.133)(PORT = 1523))
    )
  )

ENABLE_GLOBAL_DYNAMIC_ENDPOINT_LISTENER = ON
```

Set the local_listener initialization parameter. Its up to you use the number of listeners. In my case I have used both.

```
SQL>alter system set local_listener='(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.30.133)(PORT=1522))','(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.30.133)(PORT=1523))';
```

**Update**

> ORA-00119: invalid specification for system parameter LOCAL_LISTENER
>
> ORA-00132: syntax error or unresolved network name 'LISTENER1'

Oracle says-

> #### 00132, 00000, "syntax error or unresolved network name '%s'"
>
> **Cause:**  Listener address has syntax error or cannot be resolved.
>
> **Action:** If a network name is specified, check that it corresponds
>             to an entry in `TNSNAMES.ORA` or other address repository
>             as configured for your system. Make sure that the entry
>             is syntactically correct.

When we create a database and provide the listener name, Oracle creates a TNS alias in `tnsnames.ora` file and that alias is used as `local_listener` value.

```
$ cat $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/tnsnames.ora
#LISTENER1 =
#  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ora12c.dba.com)(PORT = 1522))
```

In your case the alias name should be `LISTENER_ORA12C` instead of `LISTENER1`.
I had commented that alias to simulate the scenario.

So go to the `tnsnames.ora` make sure that alias is there. Then try again to start your Oracle instance.

```
[oracle@ora12c admin]$ vi tnsnames.ora 
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/db_1/network/admin/tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

LISTENER1 =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ora12c.dba.com)(PORT = 1522))



[oracle@ora12c admin]$ sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Sun Jan 8 09:10:35 2017

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected to an idle instance.

SQL> startup
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area  838860800 bytes
Fixed Size          2929936 bytes
Variable Size         624954096 bytes
Database Buffers      100663296 bytes
Redo Buffers            5455872 bytes
In-Memory Area        104857600 bytes
Database mounted.
Database opened.
SQL> show parameter local_listener

NAME                     TYPE    VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
local_listener               string  LISTENER1
```

Reference:[Configuring and Administering Oracle Net Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NETAG/listenercfg.htm#NETAG010)

Comment: pretty much the same thing as the above answer. Thanks man. But you know there is no setting for that default listener in my listener.ora file. Where are its settings ? (Using Oracle Net Manager, I did not even see that default listener also)

Comment: nonono. I did not even get a chance to do `alter system ....` I launched the default listener ; then I connected like that `connect / as sysdba` and then when I tried `startup` it failed. So I could not even alter the system to add my other listeners....

Comment: What is the error message? Is that the one you have post in another answer's comment? I think you have chose that listener during the database creation time. You can rename listener configuration file back to original name where the definition of `LISTENER_ORA12C` exists. Then start the database.

Comment: `ORA-00119: invalid specification for system parameter LOCAL_LISTENER
ORA-00132: syntax error or unresolved network name 'LISTENER_ORA12C'`  For the value LISTENER_ORA12C, I can change it in the init file

Comment: Also when I launch `lsnrctl` for the defalult listener,  it works fine but it also says : `The listener supports no services`

Comment: @JasonKrs: I have updated my answer to address your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Based on Balazs Papp and JSapkota answers, below is a step by step of how the issue got solved. Note that you must read Balazs Papp and JSapkota answers for more details

**Step 1**

- Edit you initialization parameter file on LOCAL_LISTENER parameter to add listeners on ports different than 1521

  `local_listener='(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))' ,' (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1522))' , '(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1523))'`
- If you only have a spfile, hopefully you can do :

  `connect / as sysdba`

  `startup`

  `alter system set local_listener = '(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))' ,' (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1522))' , '(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1523))'`

**Step 2**

Connect using OS authentification and startup the database

- `connect / as sysdba` and `STARTUP PFILE = <path>/you_init_file.ora`
- If you did not have an init file and had to modify the spfile, just `shutdown immediate` and `startup` again

**Step 3**

A this point you are all set. You can open the pluggable database and disconnect from the client. After disconnecting, assuming your listener.ora and tnsnames.ora are properly configured with the LOCAL_LISTENER parameter file, and also that the listener you need to connect to is started on the server, you can re-connect to the client by that listener using `connect username/password@descriptor` where "descriptor" corresponds to the network service name associated with your custom running listener.

For further details on syntax, please read :

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NETRF/tnsnames.htm#NETRF260

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28317/listener.htm#NETRF008

Special thanks to Balazs Papp and JSapkota

Answer (score 1):

`lsnrctl start` starts the default listener, named `LISTENER`, on the port `1521`. This does not need any  configuration, this listener can be started without `listener.ora`.

> I can't practice my custom listener as if I don't put them on port
>   1521, I can NEVER user them to connect on the DB.

The database registers into a listener running on the default `1521` port without any configuration. If you want the database to be registered dynamically in other listeners listening on other ports as well, you need to set the `local_listener` parameter. For example, if you have 2 listener on ports `1521` and `1522`, you need to set the below in the database instance, with your actual hostname or IP after `HOST`:

```
alter system set local_listener='(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=...)(PORT=1521)), (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=...)(PORT=1522))';
```

Comment: Oops I think I've messed things up. 1st : I don't have the default listener in my listener.ora. I think I have delete it to add my own listeners (still lsnrctl start works fine). Second, when I started the default listener to be able to connect to the DB, I could not `startup` the database to make the changes you've suggested. It says : `ORA-00119: invalid specification for system parameter LOCAL_LISTENER
ORA-00132: syntax error or unresolved network name 'LISTENER_ORA12C'` How can I change that initialisatoin parameter now ? I saw that in my initORA12C.ora file. What should I put there ?